Как отладить, через bash, perl one-liner команду?
У меня есть скрипт, с помощью которого, в bash, я обрабатываю лог-файлы работы баз данных 1С.
Анализируя результат, вижу, что часть данных лог-файлов теряется при обработке.
Поэтому, нужно проверить работу 1 команды, т.к. после нее теряется часть данных.
Собственно, часть скрипта:
cat *.log |
perl -n -e 'if (/^\d\d:\d\d\.\d+/) {$event =~ s/.\n/<line>/g; print $event."\n"; $event = "";} $event .= $_; END{print $event};' |
head -n 100 > res.txt

Этот скрипт многострочный текст приводит в 1 строку.
Вопрос: каким образом можно отладить однострочную команду?
Есть какой-нибудь толковый мануал по этому?
Спасибо!

Конструкция head -n 100 обрезает вывод, выводя только первые 100 строк. Может быть,  остальные строки и есть потери?

Нет, так сделано специально, тут все четко. 1С выводит события системы, например, выполнение запроса к СУБД, в несколько строк, нужно эти строки трансформировать в 1 длинную. Проблема в том, что, почему-то, последнее событие получается, но оно не трансформируется в 1 строку. У меня 10 серверов различной нагрузки и везде теряется 1 крайняя строка события работы баз данных 1С
